# mean of all the columns of a panda dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-3.4

I'm trying to calculate the mean of all the columns of a DataFrame but it looks like having a value in the B column of row 6 prevents from calculating the mean on the C column. Why?

```
import pandas as pd
from decimal import Decimal
d = [
    {'A': 2, 'B': None, 'C': Decimal('628.00')},
    {'A': 1, 'B': None, 'C': Decimal('383.00')},
    {'A': 3, 'B': None, 'C': Decimal('651.00')},
    {'A': 2, 'B': None, 'C': Decimal('575.00')},
    {'A': 4, 'B': None, 'C': Decimal('1114.00')},
    {'A': 1, 'B': 'TEST', 'C': Decimal('241.00')},
    {'A': 2, 'B': None, 'C': Decimal('572.00')},
    {'A': 4, 'B': None, 'C': Decimal('609.00')},
    {'A': 3, 'B': None, 'C': Decimal('820.00')},
    {'A': 5, 'B': None, 'C': Decimal('1223.00')}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

In : df
Out:
   A     B        C
0  2  None   628.00
1  1  None   383.00
2  3  None   651.00
3  2  None   575.00
4  4  None  1114.00
5  1  TEST   241.00
6  2  None   572.00
7  4  None   609.00
8  3  None   820.00
9  5  None  1223.00
```

Tests:

```
# no mean for C column
In : df.mean()
Out:
A    2.7
dtype: float64

# mean for C column when row 6 is left out of the DF
In : df.head(5).mean()
Out:
A      2.4
B      NaN
C    670.2
dtype: float64

# no mean for C column when row 6 is part of the DF
In : df.head(6).mean()
Out:
A    2.166667
dtype: float64
```

dtypes:

```
In : df.dtypes
Out:
A     int64
B    object
C    object
dtype: object

In : df.head(5).dtypes
Out:
A     int64
B    object
C    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: What is `df.dtypes`? Column `C` is `float`?

Comment: It's `object`. But it's also `object` for `df.head(5).dtypes` so why would it work in this case? (I added the full dtypes output in my post)

Comment: So problem is, that column `C` is parsed as `string`, not as `float`,

Comment: all df is `object`, because one of column is `object` . And `object` means `string`.

Comment: You can cast column `C` to float by `df['C'] = df['C'].astype(float)`. Maybe it helps.

Comment: I still don't understand why it works differently when I remove row 6. The mean on the C column should not be available either in this case.The data of the C column do not change. There is the same type. The only difference is a value vs no value in column **B** in row 6.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem. Looks like bug in pandas or at least very unexpected behavior if intended.

Comment: Ok thanks, I created a github issue, we'll see. https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11670

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use particular columns if you need only columns with numbers:

```
In [90]: df[['A','C']].mean()
Out[90]: 
A      2.7
C    681.6
dtype: float64
```

or to change type as @jezrael advice in comment:

```
df['C'] = df['C'].astype(float)
```

Probably `df.mean` trying to convert all object to numeric and if it's fall then it's roll back and calculate only for actual numbers

Comment: Yes I saw that it works if I explicitely ask for the column before getting the mean or changing the type but isn't it a bug that it does not work when doing simply `df.mean()` because of a value in another column?

Comment: You could pass argument `numeric_only=False` and you'll get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`